# ASP.Net Core: PayPal checkout endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been searching the internet about how I can add a PayPal payment endpoint in an ASP.Net Core website but unfortunately all available recourses suggest either using the PayPal SDK library which is not supported by .Net core, or providing extremely long, useless and incomplete stories with a lot of missing parts such as the actual URL (or possible example) of the API to which I have post the payment request.

> All I'm asking for in this question is just basic information such as
>   the actual URL of the API to which I have to communicate as well as
>   the parameters I have to pass to that API and an example of the
>   response I may get (not looking for an implementation). I have been unable to find this information.

Comment: PayPal has few payment APIs. Which one are you trying to implement in ASP.Net Core?

Comment: @Win: That's actually one problem because I have never had any experience with that. Can you give me some clues ?

Comment: Well, you need to pick API that suits your need. If you do not know which one, then call PayPal and ask them to assist you.

Comment: As an addition to Garth Sebastian answer there is an examples in the PayPal github repository how to check IPN (https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples), including ASP.NET Core example:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/C%23/paypal_ipn_mvc_core.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variables in the following format:

```
private void PayPal()
{
    string _MerchantEmail = "youremailwithpaypal@domain.com";
    string _ReturnURL = "https://www.yourwebsite.com/paymentsuccess";
    string _CancelURL = "https://www.yourwebsite.com/paymentfailed";
    string _CurrencyCode = "USD";
    int _Amount = 100;
    string _ItemName = "itme1"; //We are using this field to pass the order number
    int _Discount = 10;
    double _Tax = 1.5;
    string _PayPalURL = $"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business={_MerchantEmail}&return={_ReturnURL}&cancel_return={_CancelURL}&currency_code={_CurrencyCode}&amount={_Amount}&item_name={_ItemName}&discount_amount={_Discount}&tax={_Tax}";

    Response.Redirect(_PayPalURL);
}
```

You might also need a callback URL for PayPal IPN to verify the payments status. But for your question above this should work as we are already using this code in our website.

Comment: Thanks, but how does the redirection work? what values does PayPal return? How can I get the receipt number/id upon redirection? Can you please explain these as well.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, PayPal IPN needs to be configured, from PayPal settings, and it will post back lots of variables after each payment.
You can then use those details to post-back to PayPal and verify if you got correct details.